# Is there any setting on Android studio that can changes auto-complete method arguments?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I just tried override some built-in method to use it. 
But i have a problem...
Every time I loaded it with 'ctrl + space' auto-complete way, 
that method had arguments detailed in below screen shot.

[image]

As you can see, the arguments are i, i1, b, view, viewGroup..
Originally, in android API doc, that method should be...

*getChildView(int **groupPosition**, int **childPosition**, boolean **isLastChild**, View **convertView**, ViewGroup **parent**)*

How can I get proper arguments whenever I override a method from auto-complete ?!
The only thing I can guess is just some Android Studio preference issue.
But I have not found and good solution..

All override methods show the strange arguments... whenever I auto-complete...
Is there anyone who can help me?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get proper arguments whenever I override a method from
>   auto-complete ?! The only thing I can guess is just some Android
>   Studio preference issue. But I have not found and good solution..

no it is not. You didn't install the source code for android. Open the Android SDK manager and select "`Sources for Android SDK`"